# Office UI Fabric - PeoplePicker: Cannot get createGenericItem to work

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Perhaps it's just a misunderstanding on my side, but I thought the callback for `createGenericItem` in the PeoplePicker (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/peoplepicker) was used to handle input, that cannot be matched to any of the available items, and then give the possibility to create an adhoc item for this. But, whatever I tried, the callback is never called.

I made a simple pen here for the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daGPWe?editors=0010

In the example, there are two items, Peter and Maria. If you type something different (and hit enter, tab, space, whatever) I'd expect the `createGenericItem` callback to be called, but it isn't.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a misunderstanding of the purpose of this callback? I'm unable to find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding

> but I thought the callback for createGenericItem in the PeoplePicker
>   (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/peoplepicker)
>   was used to handle input

that's correct. In order to *trigger* `IBasePickerProps.createGenericItem` function,  `IBasePickerProps.onValidateInput` function needs to be provided with `ValidationState.valid` as a return value, for example:

```
<NormalPeoplePicker
      createGenericItem={this.createGenericItem}
      onValidateInput={this.handleValidateInput}
      selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
      onResolveSuggestions={this.handleResolveSuggestions}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
/>


private handleValidateInput(input: string) {
   return ValidationState.valid;
}

private createGenericItem(input: string, validationState: ValidationState) {
   return { text: "Unknown person",  state: validationState };
}
```

[This demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hh896w) demonstrates it, once `tab` or `enter` key is clicked and value cannot be resolved to any of the available items, `Unknown person` item is getting displayed

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was missing :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did you read this somewhere in the docs or are there other resources with good examples on Office UI you can recommend?

Comment: Hm, did I accidentally delete your comment or did you delete it yourself?

Comment: Me did it ;), wanted to rephrase it to: source code plus a pretty good comments coverage so far the most reliable way to figure out how to use undocumented features

Comment: Okay, good. I was just answering to say thank you, and that this is what I feared was the case, when your comment suddenly disappeared :-) Was wondering if I mistakenly hit some button ...
So thank you :-)